# Run a specific script from a file containing multiple scripts (shell/perl)

Tags: shell

lets say I had a file(.csh)

File Contents

```
Script_1
{
 code of script1
}

Script_2
{
    code of script2
 }
.
.
.

Script_n
{

 code of script_n

}
```

Now the thing is  if we run like

```
 ./file.csh -script1 <other arguments>
```

it should execute only script 1 code
Like wise , if  we run

```
./file.csh  -script2 <other arguments>
```

it should execute only script 2 code

Can any one tell the idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Files are cheap; put each script in its own file name.

Comment: Just to help the idea of, rather than carrying multiple scripts. its better to have as a master single script!

Comment: It makes the scripts slower; all the scripts have to be fully parsed before the one you want to run can be run.  Granted, you can use common 'functions' (fragments of script -- does `csh` have functions like POSIX shells do?).  I have hundreds of programs, many of them scripts, in my private `$HOME/bin` directory (528 entries in total; 12 sub-directories; 132 executables; 384 scripts, therefore).

Comment: @Sorpigal Which one is the trend now, is perl OK!

Comment: @user1228191: `csh` hasn't been the trend for over 20 years (and there's a reason for that!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab command line parameters via `$n` where `n` is integer > 0 in order of argument passed

```
#!/bin/csh
if ($#argv < 1) then
    echo "Usage: $0 (-script1|-script2) <args>"
    exit 0
endif

if ($1 == '-script1') then
# run Script_1
else
# run Script_2
endif;
```

If you'd like to get all arguments except the first one together, you can use `shift`:

```
#!/bin/csh

// without argument by default operates on $argv which is all the arguments 
// passed via command line
shift 

echo $argv // now contains all arguments but the first
```

Comment: Can you shift the arguments so that the `-script1` is lost leaving the other arguments to be processed by the sub-script (which is quite different from a subscript, of course).

Comment: Dude, it was reporting error  "if: Malformed file inquiry." Anything Wrong!!

Comment: @user1228191 which line and what does the line look like?

Comment: i ran with -script1 as argument, why i tried to debug back with -xf , it ends here: if ( 2 < 1 ) then if ( -script1 == -script1 ) then if: Malformed file inquiry.

Comment: shouldn't that be `if('-script1' == '-script1')` ? But I'm not sure why you'd want to do that :s

Comment: even i ran with -script2 as argument, it reporting same, if('-script2' == '-script1') then if: Malformed file inquiry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10041/discussion-between-user1228191-and-niftydude)

Comment: i find that it was because of "-" in the argument name, any idea of how to allow that character

Comment: Try quoting it : `"-encounter"`

Comment: @NiftyDude
replace the line : if ($1 == '-script1') then : with : if ("$1" == "-script1") then : and try again. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, Hope it will help.

Using all_script file to store all content.
My sample file content is:

```
Script_1
{
 echo executing script1
 echo 1st arg = $1
 echo 2nd arg = $2
 echo rest arg = $*
}

Script_2
{
 echo script2  
 echo 1st arg = $1
 echo 2nd arg = $2
 echo rest arg = $*

}

Script_3
{
echo script3
 echo 1st arg = $1
 echo 2nd arg = $2
 echo rest arg = $*
}
```

My script to run this:

```
#! /bin/csh -f


set script_name = `echo $argv[1] | sed 's/-s/S/g' | sed 's/t/t_/g'`
set script_arg =  "$argv[2-$#argv]"  

#grep the relevent script
grep -A1000 $script_name all_script | grep -B1000 -m1 "}" | sed 's/Script_[0-9]//g' | sed 's/{//g' | sed 's/}//g' > myscript 
csh ./myscript $script_arg

echo "DONE :)"
```

Change the number 1000 based on maximum length of your script.
Also, Please be advised that you have used Script_1 as your script name in file. while you are trying to access it with argument -script1. My script takes care of this, however it would be better to use either one of the format and case should also be uniform... or else you will be inviting un necessary complexity.